# Master page inheritence dilemma

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

Bit of a confusion for me here. This is ASP.NET 4.0. Looking at the markup, it appears that `Default.aspx` inherits from `Site.Master` page. But looking at the class definition of `Default.aspx` (which is named `_Default`), it inherits from `Page` class and not `SiteMaster`.

Now I need to share a few functions across multiple inherited pages and was looking to add them to SiteMaster class so that they would be available in all inherited pages. Can I use SiteMaster class for my purpose, or should I add an independent module to my project and add all my functions to that?

Comment: Master page inheritance is something completely different than class inheritance in C#.

Comment: @UweKeim: That became obvious once I saw that the code-behind class of my inherited page doesn't actually inherit from `SiteMaster`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone else looking for a solution, all you need to do is to add the following directive to your markup:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

You can add this line to the top of ASPX file, just under the `<%@ Page ... %>` line. Once added, simply rebuild your project. Now all the public members of your master page class will become available through the strongly-typed member named `Master`. For example, you can now use the following code to access a public function called `MyFunc()` defined in the master page class:

```
this.Master.MyFunc(); //C#
Me.Master.MyFunc() 'VB.NET
```

`MasterType` directive actually adds a **shadowing** member named `Master` that is strongly-typed as `SiteMaster` class (or whatever master page class you have specified) when spitting the code-behind class. This new member hides the base class member (whose type is the generic `MasterPage` class) and thus allows you to access your master page members directly. The property is defined in the `.aspx.Designer.cs/vb` file like this:

```
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Master() As YourProjectNamespace.SiteMaster
    Get
        Return CType(MyBase.Master, TagTrakkerOnline2.SiteMaster)
    End Get
End Property
```